# How can I set InDesign top and bottom cell inset default values for Excel imported tables?

Tags: adobe-indesign, microsoft-office, tables, microsoft-excel

I need to import Excel tables into InDesign CS6.

In order to get the text to be visible (no red dots indicating hidden text), I have to change the top and bottom Cell Insets within InDesign to zero since they are set on 1,411mm by default (see picture attached).

[image: TAB]

I've created a cell style to remove the inset. However, because I have a large amount of tables, setting the cell style manually is a problem.

Is there a way to set these cell styles as defaults or to have the Excel import recognize the cell style upon import?

Comment: This is the kind of question which might be a good fit for the proposed Graphic Design Software Support stack. Please see the proposal and follow it if you think it might be useful. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86994/graphic-design-software-support/

Comment: Welcome cinzia! I've edited your question so it is slightly more on-topic. If you feel my changes are incorrect, please feel free to click the [eidt](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/53248/edit) link above and correct things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set up a Cell Style with the options you want, if you don't already have one created....

[image]

Then **Double click** the default `[Basic Table]` Style in that panel. Set the appropriate rows to use your Cell Style:

[image]

Then when you import the Excel table, be certain to check the **Import Options** item and set the import to use the `Basic Table` style.

[image]

**Caveat**: In many cases it's best to *not* rely on "default" styles because doing so may result in changes later you do not intend. **Ideally you would create a new table style** which uses your Cell Style, then tell the imported Excel document to use *that* unique style.